# Can interference take place in medium itself?

Tags: waves

Just a thought came when i encounter this problem , here as many beams r meeting , they can also interfere in medium like air too isnt ? I know how to solve this problem , just was curious if interference can takes place in space  ( althought it takes place on screen too ) (is my thinking right waves do interfere in space but it doesnt interfere with the intereferences happening on screen?) [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have wavefronts from coherent source overlapping then interference can occur.

Here is a still from a ripple tank to show a two dimensional interference pattern where the minima are easily seen.

[image]

With light when you place a screen remote from the light source with the two slits in between you can see the interference pattern irrespective of where the screen is placed.

Comment: Sir i got your point , just one thing the intereference is due to electric field vector addition right ? So the interfence maximas at space and on screen r due to vector addition of these electric fields right Sir ?(in my problem)

Comment: But you wrote "I know how to solve this problem , just was curious if interference can takes place in space . . . ." :-)  The answer to your question is "yes".

Comment: By saying ik how to solve this problem bc its just need geometry and path difference concept . Oo i see @Farcher Sir , then why a beam whose electric field at some point gets interferenced , will have electric field for propagation at later stage ? This will clear my full query :)

Comment: Sir should i be more clear on what i meant ?

Comment: @WayBig You did fine!

Comment: Yeah Sir but can u tell the reason behind this : if the interference occurs at some point in space , all energy of that beam is lost there in that specific point in space , so is the electric field which the beam propagates , then how does that beam propagates later on ? ( I just didnt get how there is electric field remaining for beam to propagate later on and cause interference at some other point if energy and electric field is both lost due to interference at some earlier stage ) .

Comment: Sir is the above comment i wrote is not clear ?

Comment: When you have interference you then have the energy carried by the waves along specific directions.  So although there will be regions where no energy is transferred (dark fringe) there will be other regions where there is more energy being transferred (bright fringe). Overall the total amount of energy transferred is the same as the sum of the energy from the two waves which are superposing individually.

Comment: Sir i fully agree about the statment u said , i meant to say after where those dark frnges/bright r formed , now how willl the wave which forms theese fringes propagate later on as such energy is used fully in case of bright  frienge isnt ? ( Isnt the electric field full energy got stored there so why will the wave propagate as such the electric field is fully lost in case of bright fringe isnt ?

Comment: (I am assuming the wave needs electric field to propgate always )

Comment: Sir can u pls explain ?

Comment: "Interference" is misunderstood. Interference never causes energy loss, energy is always stored in the medium at "dark" or zero amplitude locations. This is true for sound, water and even EM waves. Energy is only taken out of the medium by absorption ... like waves crashing on the beach or photons being absorbed by an atom or molecule.  The classical interpretation of the DSE says dark bands are where photons are cancelled which is a gross over simplification and this is what is widely taught until you take quantum optics.

Answer (score 0):

"Interference" is misunderstood. Interference never causes energy loss, energy is always stored in the medium at "dark" or zero amplitude locations. This is true for sound, water and even EM waves. Energy is only taken out of the medium by absorption ... like waves crashing on the beach or photons being absorbed by an atom or molecule. The classical interpretation of the DSE says dark bands are where photons are cancelled which is a gross over simplification and this is what is widely taught until you take quantum optics.

An important property of photons is they must travel an integer number of wavelengths, in the DSE there is no energy (no photons) in the dark areas, all the photons take the path to the bright areas. The photons take the most probable (quantum mechanics) path where they can transfer their energy to an atom.

In the DSE photons take a probable path to the screen but final absorption occurs in you eye!  .... of course many photons just get absorbed by the walls/apparatus.

For a beam (propagating light) we know thanks to Maxwell that an E field vector and an M field vector have a sinusoidal shape in time and distance. What is interesting is that even for a single photon the EM fields grow and shrink together from a max amplitude to zero! and this propagation repeats itself over and over until absorption. I believe it is considered a property of the EM field that it effectively contains the energy of the photon even though its E and M are zero at many points in the propagation.

Similarly if 2 photons or 2 beams are "interfering" in the EM field the EM field holds or conserves the energy. An analogy is if 2 water waves are passing into each other, for a brief second the surface of the water is completely calm ..... but a second later the waves reemerge ... the energy was stored in the elasticity/compressibility of the water.

Comment: Sir i agree with u , just wanted to know on thing as such interference is electric field vector addition, imagine it happens at one point in space due to two beams , now i just want to know why still those two beams propagate later on too to some other points in space as such it needs electric field to travel right later after interference isnt ? As such electric field is used up in causing interference

Comment: For a beam (propagating light) we know thanks to Maxwell that  an E field vector and an M field vector have a sinusoidal shape in time and distance.  What is interesting is that even for a single photon the EM fields grow and shrink together from a max amplitude to zero! and this propagation repeats itself over and over until absorption. I believe it is considered a property of the EM field that it effectively contains the energy of the photon even though its E and M are zero at many points in the propagation.

Comment: Similarly if 2 photons or 2 beams are "interfering" in the EM field the EM field holds or conserves the energy. An analogy is if 2 water waves are passing into each other for a brief second the surface of the water is completely calm ..... but a second later the waves reemerge ... the energy was stored in the elasticity/compressibility of the water

Comment: Thx a lot Sir now perfectly got it