# What is the length of a photon?

Tags: optics, photons, quantum-optics, diffraction

Some questions that look kind of similar have been asked before, and I find the answers quite confusing. I intend to ask this question in a way that clearly shows what I'm asking.

Imagine the following thought-experiment. (I don't know whether it's practical to actually do the experiment or not.)

Set up the usual double-slit experiment with a photon source that sends one photon at a time. But replace the double slits with a single pinhole. Over a period of time you should observe a diffraction pattern that looks something like this:

[image]

Now in front of the pinhole, put a metal disk with slots cut in it, that can spin.

When a slot is entirely in front of the pinhole, it should have very little effect on photons that go through the pinhole. Maybe some minimal diffraction.

When the solid disk is entirely in front of the pinhole, hardly any photons should get through. A few might take the long route around the solid metal disk and through a slot, or around the outside edge of the disk.

When the edge of a slot is close to the pinhole, it might create an observable diffraction pattern different from the open one. You can observe those effects by rotating the disk to various angles and waiting for the diffraction pattern to form.

When the disk spins, then sometimes photons can get through the pinhole and other times they can't. Most photons are independent of all of the others. (If our photon-emitter releases them at random times, very occasionally two might go through the pinhole at similar times.)

The faster the disk spins, the shorter the times that photons can get through. We can vary two things -- the rotation speed of the disk, and the "wavelength" of the photons.

My assumption from a naive reading, is that photons are point particles that travel at lightspeed. So no matter how fast the disk spins, it should have no effect on the diffraction pattern.

But classically, radiation came from an accelerated charge. A single charge with an oscillatory motion would produce a wave, and if it oscillated a thousand times then the wave it produced might continue for a thousand wavelengths.

What happens in reality? Does our single-photon source produce point-particle photons which are entirely unaffected by the spinning disk except when an edge is close to the pinhole? Or does it produce photons that have a length, that can be interrupted by the spinning disk? If they are each a thousand wavelengths long, then at some wavelength and at some rotation speed they will all be affected. If they are one wavelength long, similarly at some speed they will all be affected.

Maybe the reality simply does not match up to point-particle photons that have special properties which make them each behave statistically like a wave. And it doesn't match up to literal waves either. If these concepts are useful teaching tools that don't really fit, it would be interesting to get a clear idea what to replace them with.

Comment: In my opinion photons are linear dependent and wavelength represents a photon oscillating at a certain frequency through one full cycle. See “Single Edge Certainty” https://billalsept.com/

Comment: @BillAlsept I read your link. I notice you said "Contrary to scientific consensus, the fringe patterns observed in various slit, or edge experiments can be constructed from individual photons."

I don't know whether your ideas are contrary to scientific consensus or not, but if they are it would explain why some people disagree with you.

Comment: I challenge the anonymous downvoters to disprove my answer, which makes an unambiguous prediction of the experimental result. I also want to express again my aversion of anonymous, unmotivated downvoting. Such votes have a random effect on the quality of this site.

Comment: @my2cts I agree, allowing downvoting without discourse runs contrary to the scientific process and is counterproductive for the community.

Comment: Just an observation that one poster says a photon is infinitely long, another says it is not measured in terms of length and others provide examples of how it is measured.

Comment: See here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SDtAh9IwG-I&t=842s

Comment: @Yukterez Thank you!

Comment: @Paul Yes, I noticed that. I think this is probably a blind-men-and-elephant thing.

They are each holding onto a different part of the photon, so it feels different to them. I can't expect a single coherent explanation that fits all the different feels.

Answer (score 13):

A photon is not a point particle in the classical sense of the word (and neither is an electron, or any other fundamental 'particle'). Rather, it is a convenient word for describing some aspects of the electromagnetic field. It refers to the presence of energy in some particular 'mode' of the field. A mode can be thought of as an extended entity; it has a well-defined frequency and in free space it has a well-defined wavelength. It corresponds roughly to a plane wave.

In the type of diffraction /interference experiment in the question, the pattern observed on the screen is exactly as classical wave theory would predict, except that it appears as a set of dots rather than as completely continuous. However since the question concerns the pattern (i.e. the density distribution of the dots) we can use classical wave theory to answer the question.

The rings in the pattern occur at angles from the pinhole as given by diffraction theory. For a monochromatic source (without the chopping effect proposed in the question) the first minimum is at an angle given by
$$
\theta \simeq  1.22 \lambda / a
$$ where $\lambda$ is the wavelength and $a$ the radius of the pinhole.

If we now 'chop' the transmission through the pinhole, as proposed in the question, then the light emerging through the chopper is no longer monochromatic. It now has a range of frequencies whose spread $\Delta \nu$ is of the order of
$$
\Delta \nu \simeq 1 / \Delta t
$$
where $\Delta t$ is the time for which the pinhole is open. Consequently the light emerging from the chopped pinhole has a range of wavelengths. The range is given by
$$
\Delta \lambda \simeq \Delta \nu \left| \frac{d\lambda}{d\nu} \right|
= \frac{\lambda^2}{c} \Delta \nu
= \frac{\lambda^2}{c \Delta t}
$$
The effect of this range of wavelengths is to blur the interference pattern. The angle to the first minimum is proportional to the wavelength, so it gets blurred by
$$
\Delta \theta = 1.22 \Delta \lambda / a .
$$
It is useful to compare this blurring to the angle itself:
$$
\frac{\Delta \theta}{\theta} = \frac{\Delta \lambda}{\lambda} = \frac{\lambda}{c \Delta t}.
$$
Thus we find that when the pinhole is chopped so rapidly that it only allows through one wavelength at a time, then the diffraction pattern is completely blurred away.

To answer the overall question about "how long is a photon", the answer is that a truly monochromatic photon is infinitely long. That is, it is a way of referring to a state of excitation of a mode of infinite length and perfectly precise frequency. For more physically realistic cases the field excitation of not infinitely long; in this case one can imagine a pulse of light of some finite duration. More generally it is the coherence length that is the important quantity.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122954/discussion-on-answer-by-andrew-steane-what-is-the-length-of-a-photon).

Answer (score 3):

It's called the coherence length. It depends on how the photon was created. A photon from a short-lived excited state has a shorter coherence length than a photon (of the same wavelength) from a long lived state.

You can measure it: the easiest way to visualise this is through an interference/diffraction experiment a bit different from the one you describe. You take a standard Michelson interferometer with a non-laser source and set it up to show a fringe pattern.  Now increase the length of one of the arms.  You will still see fringes, according to whether the arriving waves are in phase or out of phase.   But as you increase the length further the pattern fades and eventually disappears, at the point when the  wave travelling the longer path arrives at the detector so late after the wave travelling the shorter path that the photon waves do not overlap. The extra path length when the pattern disappears is the length of the photon.

Comment: Thank you! I can imagine this easily with traditional wave theory. If you generate a single wavelet in water -- up and down once -- and the wave goes through a slit, you can get only three interference peaks. The center. There's a place where the up and the down cancel. There is one on each side where the up is not canceled, and beyond that a place where the down is not canceled. That's all. Given light waves that each only cancel with itself, we could get something similar. If each individual wave was only say 5 wavelets long, then....

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

There is no such thing as a photon 1000 wavelengths long, but there is such thing as an atom emitting 1000 photons, these are called quanta and are fundamental to photon/quantum theory, each one is unique and destined on its own path to be eventually absorbed by another atom/atoms/molecules. An atom takes time to emit a photon so a single atom can't overlap photons, but a laser with many excited atoms can have one "seed" photon create a cascade of many photons, these photons are separated spatially according to how the atoms are arranged.

Consider your wheel to have a pinhole instead of a slot and lets consider your wheel stopped but the pinholes slightly misaligned, obviously there will be attenuation but a few will make it thru both holes, the result is just another circular diffraction pattern as in your image but offset from your original one. If we average this over many revolutions of the wheel you are left with Gaussian (blob) distribution.  You have effectively destroyed the single slit "interference" pattern! Your wheel is very similar to what has been attempted for the DSE, you are trying to determine path information ... which is just another way of saying that you're messing with the photons and altering their originally intended path.

Finally, if your wheel was really really fast you are NOT going to be able to change the photons or break them or alter their wavelength!, they will will just behave quantum mechanically or probabilistically .... some might get thru at speed V and even less at 2V but certainly none will get thru at speed c ....which is impossible for your wheel to go anyway.

Comment: I have the impression there is more than one theory of photons. They don't all require that when a photon is absorbed by one atom, it has to be the same individual photon that another atom emitted. With wave theory, imagine that an electron is dropping from one orbital to another. If it does that while making a circular orbit around the atom, that's linearly polarized light in its plane and circularly polarized light perpendicular, and one wavelength. If it takes 1000 revolutions to reach the new orbital, that's 1000 wavelengths. How long does it take an atom to emit a photon? I don't know.

Comment: @JThomas There are many old theories and new theories about photons, there are many theories to address many different aspects of photons, there are many many more opinions than theories on what these theories mean! The photon quanta is fundamental ... I don't know of any theories otherwise ... but I have seen a few opinions.  Also some of the old theories are better than some of the newer ones! An atom can stay in an exited state for a quite a while (ms) but once the probabilities in the EM field align the emission time is very very short, wavelength over c is a good approximation.

Comment: @JThomas according to QM orbits are not circular, they are probability distributions.

Comment: Quantum theory describes things that can be observed and measured. You can't observe an atom emitting a photon without changing it drasticly. But you can measure the average state of a lot of atoms and their variance, and you can get a probability distribution for the photons they emit. There's no point in assuming specific states for individual atoms when we can never know what their specific states are. We do just as well by assuming that they never have a specific state, that each of them IS a probability distribution.

Comment: If we are observing a freeway from the air and have no way to tell the cars apart, we might best describe it as if each car followed a random path, and a certain proportion leave at each exit. For elementary particles QM is the best available description. But when physicists drive home from work to their wives and children, they would not be satisfied to drive home to random wives and children.

Comment: There is most certainly such a thing as a photon 1,000, 10,000 or a million wavelengths long by the most-standard understanding (which is to equate the coherence length with the photon length). An infinitely long photon is called a momentum eigenstate (plane wave) photon. The "long photon" limit (monochromatic, single-frequency (thus single momentum)) photons are a staple of quantum scattering calculations: see eg. R. Loudon, The Quantum Theory of Light or https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.76.062709 or

Comment: @Dast  How long is a photon is most typically described as in https://arxiv.org/pdf/0803.2596.pdf.  Also what is being discussed here is a 1000 photons, not a  special long mode of a single photon.

Comment: @JThomas If you put a high speed chopper wheel with a slot to allow the cars to pass on the highway or exit gates you will hopefully find that the cars arrive in one piece .... just like quanta do.

Comment: @PhysicsDave. Thanks for sharing the paper. The idea of "length" they introduce at the beginning (the one implied by fig.2 or fig.3) is exactly the one I was talking about. The timescale they emphasise throughout the paper (decay time of source atom) is the inverse of the photon's bandwidth (frequency spread). This timescale they refer to mutliplied by the speed of the photon (c in vacuum) is the coherence length I referred to. I think the OP is asking for a length scale to associate with a single photon (What is the Length of a photon) so a long mode photon seems a relevant thing to mention.

Answer (score -1):

Time and energy in quantum mechanics are conjugate parameters, linked by The Uncertainty Principle where: (delta t) x (delta E) is greater than or equal to Planck's Constant/4 Pi. My understanding is that...if you had a one photon 'at-a-time' source, the time location/coordinate of that one photon and its property of energy would be linked and bound by The Uncertainty Principle above. You can never be certain where that one photon is, or the exact energy that it has. So, I tend to think of a photon as yes a point particle, but with each photon somewhere 'Uncertain' within a 'packet' of say delta t in 'length', and with an amplitude energy of say delta E in the 3 spatial dimensions. One photon would illuminate one spot only on the screen. As the number of photons sent increases, The Uncertainty Principle tells us that they hit different places (coordinates) with different energies (properties). What we see then is a wave pattern of light and dark fringes. This actually shows a Probability Wave for where the photons are most likely to end up, or not. This is the meaning of 'wave-particle duality', for photons, or indeed for particles such as electrons in an electron diffraction tube where this duality may be easily demonstrated. The wave pattern and the intensity/energy of the fringes, diminishing from the centre outwards, mathematically is described by Schroedinger's second-order differential equation. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: If a photon is a point particle that travels at lightspeed with some uncertainty about its location or time, I would expect most of them to go through a slot in the disk with essentially no interaction, or else fail to go through the solid disk. So the spinning disk should have little effect on the diffraction pattern no matter how fast it spins. 

But if the photon is more like a traveling line segment, that takes time to leave its source and just as much time to pass a point, then the disk may affect it. Do you know which is true?

Comment: My guess would be that the spinning disk will make the fringes dimmer. Say the slits are a tenth of 360 degrees, then I would expect the intensity of the fringes to be a tenth of those seen without a disc in place.

Comment: Thank you. If I understand, if the slots take half the area of the disk that photons could reach, then only half of them will get through so the fringes will be dimmer. Half as many photons would result in half the detections, though that might not be half the perceived brightness.

Comment: The speed of the slits on your 'thought-experiment' rotating disc would not be anywhere need the magnitude of the speed of light. So I would not think in terms of the slots interfering with the 'probability packet' for the photon described under The Uncertainty Principle. My guess would be that the disc just reduces the number of photons going forward and so the intensity of the fringes. Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: Classically, the issue would not be lightspeed but frequency. If a wave has to complete one whole cycle to actually be a wave, and it does that at one hertz, that's a whole second that it could be disrupted passing through a slot. If a charge actually puts out a thousand cycles, that's a thousand coherent cycles and they might have more effect on a detector than just a hundred cycles. But point photons would not show any of that.

Comment: My Answer was edited by 3 knowledgeable contributing PhysicsStack people... and subsequently down voted... So, I've now un-edited it...and been awarded a Cleanup Badge, whatever that means... It's not very encouraging or helpful for someone just to downvote an answer with no constructive explanation for anyone, especially for the originator of the question...

Comment: Radiative Lifetimes can be measured in a gas at low pressure in a tube. Excite the electrons with an alternating field from a coil wrapped around the tube. Modulate the alternating field. Measure the phase lag between the input and photon output signals. This gives the Radiative Lifetime.

Comment: Thank you! When I look up "radiative lifetime" I mostly get things about semiconductors. When an electron is put into a higher orbital and not stimulated, it takes a random time before it radiates. I don't see how this relates to my question, but there's a lot of interesting information there which relates to a lot of things.

Answer (score -1):

Often, as in some answers here, the terms photon and electromagnetic wave are used as synonyms. Yet they mean very different things. An em wave has wavelength, frequency and coherence length and time. A photon just has energy, momentum and spin. It is a dimensionless point particle as far as we know. The wave describes the probability of finding photons with given energy, momentum and spin at at given place and time. It is similar to an electron wave function in this respect.

In your thought experiment the transmission is not only position dependent, as in the traditional slit, but also time dependent. Classically this means that your original monochromatic wave is amplitude modulated and now consists of a band of frequencies. In photon terms you will observe a distribution of photon energies, each following their own probability distribution or diffraction pattern. However, in practice such effects are unobservable since mechanical chopping cannot be done at optically relevant frequencies. You will just observe the same interference pattern as without chopping, but chopped.

Comment: Why is the correct answer downvoted? This is poor judgment.

Comment: I challenge the anonymous downvoters to disprove my answer, which makes an unambiguous prediction of the experimental result. I also want to express again my aversion of anonymous, unmotivated downvoting. Such votes have a random effect on the quality of this site.

Comment: It looks to me like your predictions are the same as Andrew Steane's predictions (but he gave some math to say it more precisely), and different from user291781's predictions. Likely the downvoting was for some other reason than predicted results.

Comment: @my2cts initially I did downvote but have just now changed it. I will admit it was hastily applied on what I thought you were saying. Although I view The idea of a photon different than you I don’t necessarily see anything in your answer to disagree with. I don’t know about a point Particle but I believe all photons are the same size and anything to do with length must be talking about the distance a photon travels during one full cycle of oscillation between amplitudes. The position and time dependent aspect of photons are noticed in polarizer experiments proportional to cos2theta.

Comment: @my2cts I am not one of your dvotes. But my guess for the reason is (1) You are right, but a better answer would persuade me that it is right, by providing evidence (eg links, quotes) or a convincing argument. Not just a flat statement of "this is the case as far as we know". (2) Photons have several senses of "length": wavelength, coherence length and its possible they may also have finite radius. You only discuss the last of these. The OP's title question is asking for radius, but their proposed experiment picks out the coherence length, while wavelength is the one everyone has heard of.

Comment: @Dast  yes I agree on the radius aspect of a photon. When polarizers line up photons have no problem going through but perpendicularly they will not fit.

Comment: @Dast So correctness no longer matters. Answers should entertain people into a comfortable illusion of understanding with wordy illustrated answers or perhaps a video. Want popcorn?

Comment: @my2cts I'm not a dvote. But I would say that the proposed experiment will allow certain quanta thru based in probability and the position of the slot. The quanta themselves (say red laser ones) will not be altered in any way so I'm not sure what you mean by a band of frequencies. Also I would say photons have size properties .... point particles per the std model has its own  implications/limitations ... but for the std model its a helpful definition.

Comment: @Dast  The OPs experiment will not produce a measure of coherence length ... one reason being it consists of single photons .. for coherence length we need a population of photons.

Comment: @PhysicsDave Does coherence length depend on a statistical property of large numbers of photons, or could it be due to a property of single photons that shows up when there are large numbers? Polarization and diffraction are a property of single photons. One single photon interferes with itself when it passes through two slits. It doesn't need a second photon to interfere with.

Comment: @JThomas It would be interesting to consider "sending one photon at a time" into the interferometer ..... what would the pattern look like and what would be the length measurement?  Infinite, zero or just na(not applicable) or just lambda itself. A "photon interferes with itself" it just a historical and somewhat misleading statement, a more modern understanding is that each photon is able to determine its own path .... so the really important question is how is it able to do that?

Comment: @PhysicsDave Thank you. It's hard to get the wording just right. The interferometer gives you two paths that take different times to traverse. A wave would self-interfere with different parts of the same wave arriving at the same time. A traditional particle would take just one path and not interfere with itself at all. What actually happens must be something else.

Comment: As near as I can tell, modern physics says that QM gives the correct statistical results so it is true. But no one has a way to visualize it that is understandable. An ideal visualization would not only give a sense why things happen, but also why the things that don't happen, don't happen. It might not be "true", but it would in general correctly predict what happens.

Comment: @JThomas Think of a photon as a well localized travelling ripple in a field called the EM field.  See one of my answers here about "interference" : https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/623648/can-interference-take-place-in-medium-itself/626362#626362

Comment: @JThomas Here is another one : https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/589681/why-dont-photons-interfere-interact-with-one-another-as-common-mechanical-wave/589697#589697  Get rid of the word "interference" if you want to understand at the quantum level, a single photon won't even go into an interferometer if the set path lengths aren't ideal (multiples of the wavelength)  ... the photon will just be reflected just as when you place a mirror in front of your telescope .... it took millions of years to get here and we can just send it away.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'll comment on the statement "It is a dimensionless point particle as far as we know." Sometimes people say this to mean that the photon isn't composite -- that it corresponds to a basic field in the Standard Model's lagrangian. With that meaning, it's true. But in the context of the question, calling it a dimensionless point particle might suggest a hidden-variables interpretation. With that meaning, it's presumptuous: quantum theory works fine without that idea, even if the idea can be made to work (and as far as I know it hasn't, not with the same scope as QED).

Comment: @Chiral Anomaly This does not suggest a hidden-variables interpretation anymore than calling an electron a point particle does so. This is mainstream physics. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron

Comment: What Wikipedia describes as an upper bound on the size of an electron is a result about the scale at which electrons have been probed without finding any evidence of compositeness (the first part of my comment). Good texts are careful to explain this, but not everybody appreciates this nuance. Without clarification, a person might misinterpret the point-particle language to mean something like "at any given instant, the electron is localized at a specific point whether or not we're measuring it's location," which is the classic example of a hidden variables interpretation.

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly The photon size is zero in the following sense: 'Moreover, the interactions of the particle can be represented as a superposition of interactions of individual states which are localized. ... is in this sense that physicists can discuss the intrinsic "size" of a particle: The size of its internal structure, not the size of its wavepacket. The "size" of an elementary particle, in this sense, is exactly zero.' https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_particle

Comment: Yes, that's true, at least in nonrelativistic QM. (Side note: It's only approximately true in relativistic QFT because particle-creation operators con't commute with local observables in relativistic QFT, but the approximation is plenty good enough for this question.) Similarly, an eigenstate of the angular momentum operator with spin "up" along the $z$-axis can be written as a superposition of more than one spin-value along the $y$-axis. I was only commenting that a person reading the answer might not know (or might incorrectly assume) what you meant by "point particle."

Answer (score -4):

We can determine photon duration given:

1. sunlight power flux of 1370 $W / m^{2}$
2. sunlight photon flux of $10^{18} / m^{2}$

Watts $\left( J/s \right)$ per photon of sunlight $= 1.37 \cdot 10^{15}$

Energy of green light photon (mid-point of sunlight spectrum, average energy) $= 4.3 \cdot 10^{-19} J  \left( h \cdot f \right)$

Divide energy of photon by power of photon to determine time duration per photon $\left( J / W \right) = 3.13 \cdot 10^{-4} s$.

Multiply the time found above by $c$ to get length: 93,837.4 $m$ per photon.

This applies to all photons, not just visible light, since $h$ is in $J s/cyc$

Additionally, dividing $h$ by this time gives us the energy per cycle of field displacement

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/377876)

Comment: The answer is provided: “Multiply by c to get length: 93,837.4 m”